# Ending Postgres Query without leaving the command line - Get back to command line automatically

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql

Whenever I run a Postgres query it appears that you have to completely quit out of the command line.

I have seen it done where you can press `CTRL-C` and you are taken back to the `PSQL` command line i.e., `databasename=>`. Additionally, if I am in the middle of viewing results and I press `CTRL-C`, how can I have Postgres send me back to `databasename=>`?

**Bonus:**

Is there a way to script is so if I type usedb databasename folllwed by psql, Postgres will know which database I am referring to and automatically connect me to it so I dont have to type \connect databasename ?

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about what you're experiencing? What happens when you press 'ctrl-c' while a query is running? Also, have you looked at the [psql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)? There is information there which might be useful to your bonus question.

Answer (score 0):

Once a postgres query has run and has returned its table of results in the 'psql' command line environment it should drop you back in to the same database that you ran the previous command from.

If you want to connect directly to a database from your terminal :

```
 psql -d nameofdatabase
```

If you want to connect using a script you can access postgres by url :

```
postgres://username:password@localhost/nameofdatabase
```

where 'localhost' could be replaced by the ip of the database you are trying to connect to if its not on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pressing `Ctrl-C`, press `Ctrl-D`. In Unix, `Ctrl-D` is the End-of-File (EOF) character. That is what will make `psql` quit---just like if you fed it a script on stdin and it got to the end. It works in many other REPLs too, like `irb`, `rails console`, `python`, `R`, `bash`, etc.

The reason `Ctrl-C` doesn't exit is so that you can use it to abort an individual command, e.g. a long-running query.

**EDIT**: Also, if you are viewing results and they are paged (they appear on a new screen and you can scroll up and down), you can get back to the `psql` prompt by typing `q`. That's because by default the pager used is just `less`. You can say `man less` to read more about it. Or experiment with it on any text file: `less /etc/services`.

Personally I find paging in psql annoying, so I turn it off by creating a file named `~/.psqlrc` with this line:

```
\pset pager
```

(Also, sorry if you know this already: `~` is just an abbreviation for "my home directory". So `~/.psqlrc` is the same as `/home/whatever/.psqlrc`.)

**Bonus**: If you want to connect to a specific database, you can say `psql -d foo` or even just `psql foo`.

Answer (score 0):

just enter \q or q in the psql terminal